# Android MediaPlayer - exception thrown from setdatasource native method

Tags: android

the following code i am using for playing

```
MediaPlayer mp3;
mp3=new MediaPlayer();
mp3.setDataSource("/beep.mp3");
mp3.start();
```

exception is thrown from setdatasource native method

can anyone help me in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Just put your file in asset folder n apply this code..

```
Media Player mp = new MediaPlayer();    

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = contex.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
    mp.setDataSource( descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength() );
    descriptor.close();
mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
```

Comment: ** i had tried this but it is saying prepare native method.R u having any other suggestions freind**

Comment: **03-31 12:52:15.494: WARN/System.err(11359): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
**

Comment: see this ques.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219722/android-media-player-problem/5219756#5219756

Answer (score 0):

1. check your file path, or use FileDescriptor
2. dont forgot prepare before start