# Mediaplayer Stops playing

Tags: android, media-player

In our Gamefield class do we want to start a simple Mediaplayer with a Backgroundmusik like this

```
public GameField(Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // get an instance of the gameLoop
    setFocusable(true); // events happen on this view

    //Starting soundloop
    MediaPlayer play = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.coryphee_coryphee);
    play.setLooping(true);
    play.start(); ......
```

This actually stops after some time playing the musik. 
In our Mainacivity do we start a Mediaplayer like this and it does not stop playing.

Why does it stop and how can if fix it? We fixed it with running it in a Thread but i think it should work like this.
Every tutorial i could find do it like this so i am a bit helpless

Best Regards and thanks alot.

Comment: Is that view object active and visible the entire time as well?  If the object that owns the `MediaPlayer` gets garbage collected for any reason, playback will cease.

Comment: Yes it's our serface view where we render the picture.  (Canvas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaPlayer stop playing after about 5 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this one it is the same case for you.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds)

but i think it is something else at your case.

Comment: This actually worked for us. I wonder why it does this. We defined it as private Metiaplayer play and it still stoped. As Static it worked. 

Thanks