# JavaFX MediaPlayer - Music stops after 10 seconds

Tags: java, javafx, mp3

Here's the code, like the title says the music stops after 10ish seconds, i played the file normally in vlc or other programs, it lasts more than 5 minutes.

```
public void music(){
        String bip = "src/data/fjordmusic.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(Paths.get(bip).toUri().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
```

Comment: This is strange. Can you add more data, like your platform details to the question?

Comment: Removed duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds ) since even though the solution is the same, the other question asks about android, not javafx...

Answer (score 23):

Your question was already asked and answered here:
[MediaPlayer stop playing after about 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds)

It seems that the garbage collector ereases the MediaPlayer instance after finishing the method. Put the declaration of MediaPlayer above the method and it should work.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer
public void music(){
    String bip = "src/data/fjordmusic.mp3";
    Media hit = new Media(Paths.get(bip).toUri().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

(I'm not able to post comments, so I'm forced to write an answer.)

Comment: I actually had to move the entire instantiation outside of the method, not only the declaration. The link you posted actually is not pointing to a JavaFX problem, but it's interesting to observe the same behavior.

Comment: I doubt that I would have gotten to the point where I would make the garbage collector responsible for that. You saved me a lot of time! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Try AudioClip instead:

> javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;

```
    public void music(){
        String bip = "src/data/fjordmusic.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(Paths.get(bip).toUri().toString());
        AudioClip mediaPlayer = new AudioClip(hit.getSource());
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
```