# Android Media Player implementation randomly stops playing: Error (1 -1007)

Tags: loops, android-mediaplayer, ogg

My Android Media Player randomly stops playing. I dont know why. I am using two Media Players for a gapless loop. After a while the sound stops. The issue appers after seconds or minutes. I tried several fixes:

- declaring static media player (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds))
- reducing bitrate (now i have 64 bit/s ogg files)
- setWakeMode() (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds))

None of them solved my problem. Any suggestions? THX!

Code:

```
private Context context;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable myRunnable;

/*Ausgabe*/

private ImageView cover;    
private static MediaPlayer mp;
private static MediaPlayer mp2;
private Uri myUri;
private String curTitle;
private String curPow;
private boolean curMP; //false=mp1, true= mp2

/*Control*/

private ToggleButton onoff;
private Spinner spinner;
private Switch throttle;

/*Volume*/

private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jukebox);
    context = this;

    /*Control-Setup*/
    initControls();
    initButtons();

    /*Sound Setup*/

    mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
    mp2 = new MediaPlayer();    //workarround f gapless looping
    setDisc("classic");

    /*Image Setup*/
    cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageGallerie);
    cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.classic);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mp!=null){
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
    }
    if(mp2!=null){
        mp2.stop();
        mp2.release();
        mp2=null;
    }
}

/*sound-file selection*/
public void setDisc(String s){
    String tmp = "";
    if(throttle.isEnabled()==true && throttle.isChecked())
        tmp="2";
    myUri = getUri(s+tmp);
    curTitle=s;
    curPow=tmp;
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDataSource(context, myUri);
        mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mp.prepare();
        mp2.reset();
        mp2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp2.setDataSource(context, myUri);
        mp2.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mp2.prepare();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        setMyLoop();
                        play();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Arrr, devensive programming... change request
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/*Gapless Looping - api 16 oder higher */
public void setMyLoop(){
    final AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(getRawId(this, curTitle.concat(curPow)));
    mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mp2.setNextMediaPlayer(mp);
        }
    });

    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.error2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
        }
    });
}

/*play sound*/
public void play(){
    if(onoff.isChecked()){
        mp.start();
    }
}

/*gui control*/
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == onoff){
        if(onoff.isChecked()==false){
            mpAnhalten();
        }
        else{
            mpStarten();
        }
    }
    ...
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mp!=null)
        mpAnhalten();
}

/*pause player*/
public void mpAnhalten(){
    if(mp2.isPlaying()){
        mp2.pause();
        curMP=true;
    }
    else {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
        }
        curMP=false;
    }
}

/*start player again*/
public void mpStarten(){
    if(curMP==true)
        mp2.start();
    else
        mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    View v = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    if(mp!=null && onoff.isChecked())
        mpStarten();
}

/*volume*/
private void initControls(){
    try{
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        getApplicationContext();
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   
        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/*gui-control sound-file selection*/
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if(selection.equals("Classic")){
        cover.setImageResource(getImageId(this, "classic"));
        cover.invalidate();
        throttle.setEnabled(true);
        setDisc("classic");
    }
    ...
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

...

/*oncreate submethode*/
private void initButtons(){

    /*On Off*/
    onoff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
    onoff.setChecked(false);
    onoff.setOnClickListener(this);


    /*track selection*/
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Modern");
    ...
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    /*power*/
    throttle = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.throttle);
    throttle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            setDisc(curTitle);
        }
    });
    throttle.setChecked(false);
}
```

Edit:

This is the log output:

07-26 16:07:58.707: W/SoftVorbis(191): vorbis_dsp_synthesis returned -135

07-26 16:07:58.779: E/NuPlayerDecoder(191): Stream error for OMX.google.vorbis.decoder (err=-1007), EOS successfully queued

07-26 16:07:58.780: E/NuPlayer(191): received error(0xfffffc11) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down

07-26 16:07:58.780: E/MediaPlayer(30858): error (1, -1007)

07-26 16:07:58.781: E/MediaPlayer(30858): Error (1,-1007)

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I changed my implementation from MediaPlayer to SoundPool.