# Where do i put file(.mp3) in order for it to be read?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am usinf the JavaFx method of playing music files but it isn't working (sound not playing). I feel the problem lies in my files location. Where do I put the .mp3 in my java projects folder for it to be referenced with a simple string as so? Or is there another way to reference it? JavaFX Media takes a String parameter.

```
String test = "test.mp3";
Media x = new Media(test);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(x);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: have you already tried passing in the file path along with the file? like "C:/Users/You/Documents/Java Projects/Project 1/test.mp3"

Comment: Yes, it gave me an error mentioning illegal characters. I have a resource folder that i added in my referenced libraries which i am able to reference files in there regardless of the hard drive the program is run on but that also doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read the JavaDoc of `Media`, then you know that you have to give a http, file or jar URI to the constructor you are using.
Actually from looking at the source code I wonder that you are not getting an `IllegalArgumentException`.

However, use `Class.getResource(...).toURI().toString()` to get the String you want to give to the `Media` constructor.
The combination of which `Class` object you call this on and what you give to the `getResource()` method depends on how you layout your files.
If you have your file besides your class, `getClass().getResource("file.name")` should work.
If you have your file in the root of your classpath, `getClass().getResource("/file.name")` should do.

You can give any other valid http, file or jar URI to the contructor too of course.

Comment: Heres my full method
    public static void playSong()
        String test = getClass().getResource("test2.mp3").toURI().toString(); 
        Media x = new Media(test);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(x);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

Under getClass(), it gives an error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object. I put the test2.mp3 file in the same package as my Sound class(the class that contains this method). Sorry about this weird comment. I'm new to this website

Comment: Well, if you are in static context, do not use `getClass()`, but `YourClassName.class` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. For those viewing this and having the problem of Toolkit not being initialized, refer to this: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2013/05/11/how-to-fix-toolkit-not-initialized-error-in-java-fx/#comment-9240

And for those having trouble with MediaPlayer muting after 5 seconds, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds